# Removing duplicate letters WITHOUT using join or set

Tags: python, python-3.x

my task is to remove duplicate letters in a string

```
remove_repeat(msg):
```

example

- `remove_repeat("bookkeeper")` → `'bokeper'`
- `remove_repeat("aaabcaaddddeff")` → `'abcadef'`
- `remove_repeat("a")` → `'a'`

The code I have so far is

```
def remove_repeat(msg):

    removed=[]
    for i in msg:
        if i not in removed:
            removed.append(i)
    return removed
```

I don't know how to continue with this code. I am not allowed to use 'join' or 'set'. A hint given was using += but I don't know how to incorporate that here

Comment: Do you know what `+=` does with strings?

Comment: Crack open the interpreter and give it a try. `removed = '';removed += 'b';print(removed)`.

Comment: I really wish professors wouldn't give assignments like this... I feel like there have to be lots of more creative problems that can teach students control flow and logic without teaching them to do a problem the most inefficient way possible...

Comment: @mgilson: It's most likely an intro to programming class, the point _is_ to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @mgilson: Amusingly, in CPython, this isn't actually that inefficient. They special case repeated string concatenation, so it doesn't suffer from Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm too badly. But doing the same thing in other interpreters ([including Cython](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35787022/364696)) will have serious problems.

Comment: @ShadowRanger -- You're still suffering from the `O(N)` lookup in seen characters at each iteration of the loop, which goes away if you can just use a `set` to store the seen characters (and really doesn't change the logic _at all_). . .

Comment: @mgilson: Well, in the correct version of the code (which only removes consecutive repeats), you don't do a `O(n)` lookup.

Comment: Oh, I see -- It is only _consecutive_ repeats that should be removed.  Yeah, that does make the problem more interesting.  It's not clear in the wording of the problem that is what is desired -- Only in the examples.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a `list` to accumulate results, the only good way to turn it back into a `str` is with `''.join`. But since this is a class assignment, you can be bad, and just do repeated `str` concatenation to avoid a `list` entirely:

```
def remove_repeat(msg):
    newmsg = ''
    for let in msg:
        if let not in newmsg:
            newmsg += let
    return newmsg
```

That follows your logic and the rules, but it still gets the logic wrong, since the goal is to remove *consecutive* repeats, not all duplicates of the same latter. To fix, you'd track only the last letter:

```
def remove_repeat(msg):
    newmsg = ''
    for let in msg:
        # Only append if last letter of the string to date differs from this letter
        if let != newmsg[-1:]:  # Use slice to avoid special casing first letter
            newmsg += let
    return newmsg
```

`let != newmsg[-1:]` can also be done as `not newmsg.endswith(let)`, not sure if you're allowed to use `str` methods, so I stuck with the slice test.

Just for the record, if I were implementing this outside a class, and inputs might be large (and I had some strong need to optimize it, who knows why) I'd do:

```
 from operator import itemgetter
 from itertools import groupby

 def remove_repeat(msg):
     return ''.join(map(itemgetter(0), groupby(msg)))
```

but that's probably being a little too clever. `groupby` is grouping consecutive repeated letters into groups, `map(itemgetter(0),` keeps on the group key (the single letter of the repeated group), and `''.join` stitches it all back together.

Comment: BTW, I changed the name to `newmsg` only because `removed` made me think it was where you put the stuff you dropped, not the stuff you kept, which felt rather misleading.

Comment: While this does solve OP's immediate issue, it doesn't seem like it solves the assignment. It fails with the first and second examples. Seems like the assignment is to group consecutive identical letters.

Comment: I get the logic behind this and it makes sense but it fails about half my tests.

Comment: Returns the wrong result. OP actually wants to substitute series of repeated characters with a single character. Your code produces `'bokepr'`. The desired output is `'bokeper'`. In addition, this should be doable in O(n).

Comment: @VincentSavard: Ah. Should have checked provided examples. Will update.

Comment: @timgeb, @VincentSavard, @Jessica: Added corrected version (which is in fact `O(n)`).

Answer (score 0):

Note that both previous solutions remove *all* following copies of each letter, not just immediately following ones.

Instead,

```
def remove_repeat(msg):
    previous = None
    result = ''
    for ch in msg:
        if ch != previous:
            result += ch
            previous = ch
    return result
```

Comment: He said that he cannot use join but should use +=

Comment: @sabbahillel: D'oh! Fixed now.

Comment: @HughBothwell yes so this code works for the tests as well as others I found that use the function 'join' However, I am not allowed to use this function even at the end

Comment: Great minds "think alike" (:-) If I had seen your answer before I typed in mine, I would have not entered mine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your second example `remove_repeat("aaabcaaddddeff") → 'abcadef'` will not appear with your code. The second group of a's will still fail because 'a' is already in `remove`. You need to test each letter against the immediate predecessor in remove.

Secondly, += with strings is the same an append. The following lines are equivalent.

```
mystring += mychar
mystring = mystring + mychar
```

Start by initializing remove to the first entry in msg (since it cannot be a duplicate). Now loop over the rest of msg, testing each new character against the immediate predecessor in remove. If it does not match then

```
result += newchar

def remove_repeat(msg):
    previous = None
    result = ''
    for newchar in msg:
        if newchar != previous:
            result += newchar
            previous = newchar
    return result
```